# Python : Dijkstra between two points in sparse metric graph

Tags: python, graph, dijkstra

I am dealing with very large (but sparse) metric graph `G`, with say `N = 20000` vertices but not so many edges, allowing to store (using `scipy.sparse.matrix` class) the corresponding `N x N` weight matrix.

I would be interested in the shortest path length matrix (distance on the graph), but I can't store the `N x N` distance matrix (which won't be sparse anymore). Therefore, I selected a small number `k` of vertices, and I would be interested into computing the `k x k` pairwise shortest path distances between these vertices.

The function `scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.html) might be adapted (with the argument `indices`) but it computes the distances between points to all the vertices on the graph - so a `k x N` matrix. Along with the overkill in running time, it could lead to memory issus as well.

Basically I would be ok to call a function `dijkstra(G, i, j)` that will give me the shortest path length between vertices i and j in the graph `G`. I know I can implement it by myself, but I would prefer to rely on an optimized version of it, and it would seem crazy to me that this is not implemented in some standard Python library (numpy, scipy...).

PS : Additionally, if you know a Python library that take advantage of knowing that the `G` is a metric graph, and thus for example the shortest path between two connected vertices is the weight of the corresponding edge, etc. it would be very informative :-)

PS2 : Note that I don't need the shortest paths. Only shortest path length.

PS3 : To fix idea, these graphs are built from triangulated 3D shapes. This is why these are sparse metric graphs.

Comment: You can try the networkx library; the shortest path functionality can be found [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html).

Comment: Hey, that sounds nice :) will try that soon and if it works as expected, you can write an answer so I accept you :-)
PS : any clue about how to leverage the metric property of the graph ? (I don't even know if it has advantages).

Comment: Not sure if this merits an answer, it is just a reference. You could use the metric property by setting the `weight` attribute for each edge.

Comment: Well I tried it and it seems to meet my expectations so far. Just did not hear about it yet (and when I search for "dijkstra in python" I did not get it on DDG or Google). 
Regarding the metric property, I am not sure to understand what you mean by setting weight attribute. By "metric graph", I mean that my weights satisfy the triangle inequality. My intuition leads me to think this could help to optimize dijkstra, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Ok I push a bit further using networkx. It's is **really** slow, that's a shame ! 
Computing the shortest path distance between two points is 5 times slower than... computing shortest path distances between the two points and the rest of the graph (with 20000 vertices !) using scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra.
I can't believe it and have no way to explain such a difference.